# What do the coefficients mean when using PolynomialFeatures?

Tags: scikit-learn

When using PolynomialFeatures from Scikit Learn, say you use a degree of 3, when you call `.coef_` on the new model using Polynomials you end up with an array with 3 numbers. What does each coefficient mean?

Is it:

- First number: change in y for every 1 unit change in x
- Second number: change in y for every 1^2(squared) unit change in x
- Third number: change in y for every 1^3(cubed) unit change in x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes . You could easily check this by substituting the values of x .
y = a0 + a1x + a2x(square) + a3 x(cube)
a0 will be the intercept